# How to set static path in Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I want to set my http server's static directory, and put some pictures in it, so that users can get my pictures use the url. But I failed, code below does not work:

```
# 静态路径
STATIC_DIRNAME = "resources"
# 设置static path
settings = {
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), STATIC_DIRNAME),
}

# and I passed settings to Application
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/pictures", handler.PicturesHandler),
], **settings)
```

How can I set the static directory to "resources"?

(I want to get my picture through url such as: `localhost:8888/resources/1.jpg`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [static_url_prefix](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings)

```
settings = {
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), STATIC_DIRNAME),
    "static_url_prefix": "/resources/",
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you. May you tell me why ?

Comment: @ErumHuang Please see the docs https://tornado-zh.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/web.html#id2    You can serve static files by sending the static_path setting as a keyword argument. We will serve those files from the /static/ URI (this is configurable with the static_url_prefix setting), and we will serve /favicon.ico and /robots.txt from the same directory.  http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html